# Iterate and compare within lambda in Python

Tags: python, lambda

NON-HOMEWORK

I have list of floats `x`, and I want to turn it into list `y`, a list of all the tenth elements in `x`.

For my own reasons, I really want to do this in a tiny amount of lines. I came up with something like this:

```
i = 0
y = filter(lambda x: (++i)%10; x)
```

Theoretically this should work, `i` is already defined, and the `++i` would typically add one to variable `i`, then go about the expression.

Unfortunately, `++` doesn't exist in Python.

Any Pythonic ways to go about this?

Another idea I had was to use a map, and have the expression push elements onto list `y`.

Let me know if I can be more clear.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [**Extended slices**](http://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.3.html#extended-slices):

```
>>> x = range(1,101)
>>> y = x[9::10] # 9 -> start from 10th, 10: step
>>> y
[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
```

Comment: Beautiful. Hadn't seen this before, as, though I've been using Python for a while, I haven't fully explored a lot of the more Pythonic ways of doing things. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

What about `[value for index, value in enumerate(list_of_floats) if index % 10 == 0]`?

Comment: It's worth noting that slicing is better in this case. However, this technique is worth knowing in cases where the filtering criterion is more complex.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative that use [`itertools.count`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count):

```
>>> x = range(1, 101)
>>> i = itertools.count(1)
>>> y = filter(lambda item: next(i) % 10 == 0, x)
>>> y
[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
```